# How can I filter some numbers and make a new list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I was trying to filter and make a new list.

For example if I have

```
list(3,[1,2,3,4,5],R)
```

the result will be

> R=[4,5]

but I don't know why it doesn't work

```
mayor(X,W):-
X>W.

list(Element,[Head|Tail],R):-

mayor(Element,Head),

append([Head],[],R),

list(Element,Tail,R).
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Do "duck debugging": explain to your rubber duck why you think this predicate should work.

Comment: I had to google duck debugging. Interesting idea that may cut down quite a few questions on here.

Comment: Please explain properly what your "filter" is. Right now it is difficult to know what the filtering criterion is.

Comment: `append([Head],[],R)` is the same as `R=[Head]`. If you replace `R` with `[Head]` and get rid of this line, does it help you see the problem?

Comment: Also, you have one case here, you will at least need one more to handle the empty list. When working with recursive structures like lists in Prolog, you always need to consider the cases that exist for that structure, which for lists is `[]` and `[H|T]`.

Comment: By filter I mean that only numbers greater than Element will make it to the Result

Comment: Does it have to work with unsorted lists, or only with sorted lists ?